# How to CONCATENATE multiple findings into a SINGLE CELL if MULTIPLE MATCHES are found

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

Having a prob w/ this code, not sure how to update it to concatenate the findings into one cell if it finds more than one match? It worked great in my scaled down test file but when I attempted to use it in my real file (it errored out with a "Run-time error '13':" Type mismatch...

I figured out it must be because it found MORE THAN ONE Part # match and didn't know how to respond.
Ultimately it needs to CONCATENATE all findings into one cell (the single cell it was supposed to paste its finding).

```
**' ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
**'THE GOAL**
**' >>>> IF Worksheet1 "BOM Worksheet" "P" matches Worksheet2 "INDEX" "A",**
**' >>>> then copy adjacent data from Worksheet2 "INDEX" "B" into Worksheet1 "BOM Worksheet" "S"**
**' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++****
```

**Visual Example:**
If you look in a book for the word "dog", and the adjacent data you need to collect is his name: "FIDO", you'd record the fact you found: "FIDO"

You'd move down to the next row and look for the word "cat" and the adjacent data name is: "TOM", found on pg 7 you'd record the fact you found: "TOM"

**BUT WAIT!! It found "cat" again on page 12 "KITTY" and again on pg 16!! "BOB"**
**I need the code to record all findings of "cat" ("TOM","KITTY","BOB")** in the original cell it was supposed to paste the finding if it had only been a single finding. The result would look like this: `"TOM","KITTY","BOB"`

How do I fix this code to record all findings into one cell if multiples are found?

```
Sub MOD_50_LookupCopyPasteDiffSheet()
    Dim rng1 As Range, c1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c2 As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lnLastRow1 As Long, lnLastRow2 As Long

     'Create an object for each worksheet:
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("BOM Worksheet")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("INDEX")

     'Get the row number of the last cell containing data in each sheet:
    lnLastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    lnLastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     'Create range objects for the two columns to be compared:
    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("P2:P" & lnLastRow1)
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A2:A" & lnLastRow2)

     'Loop through each cell in col A in sheet 2:
    For Each c2 In rng2

         'Check if the cell is not blank:
        If c2.Value <> "" Then

             'Loop through each cell in col B in sheet 1:
            For Each c1 In rng1

                 'Test if cells match: <<<<<<< THIS IS WHERE THE CODE ERRORS OUT
                If c1.Value = c2.Value Then

                     'Copy value from sheet 2 to sheet 1:
                    c1.Offset(0, 2).Value = c2.Offset(0, 1).Value

                     'Move on to next cell in sheet 2:
                    Exit For '(exits the "For Each c1 In rng1" loop)

                End If
            Next c1
        End If
    Next c2
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the values in `rng1` and `rng2` of the same data type, in other words, are you always comparing two values of the same data type in `If c1.Value = c2.Value Then` (string against string, number against number)

Comment: Yes. Here's a specific example:  I'm comparing a Part # to a Part # "9340MX43G04" which comes back as "FALSE" when I do an "=ISNUMBER".  The adjacent data that is to be extracted and copied and concatenated is Figure/Refc data such as: "Fig 12 2-25".  We are working with a Technical Order that a particular part may show up in Fig 12 2-25 and also show up in Fig 24 2-7, I need to know/collect all the Figure Refcs and place them into one cell. (there won't be that many) but I'm working with hundreds of rows and files...

Comment: If you try `If CStr(c1.Value) = CStr(c2.Value) Then` is it working?

Comment: Is this what you meant for me to do?  If so, no, I'm getting an error on this line: [code] If c2.Value <> "" Then [/code]    Here's what I changed the code to look like: [code]
             
                 'Test if cells match:
                'If c1.Value = c2.Value Then
                If CStr(c1.Value) = CStr(c2.Value) Then[/code]

Comment: I get runtime error 13 Type mismatch with this line of code highlighted in yellow... `If c2.Value <> "" Then`

Comment: Ok but from the code in your question, it is written that the error is occuring at the line `If c1.Value = c2.Value Then`  Also, I ran your code and it's working fine on my side.  I cannot figure out what is going wrong, sorry.

Comment: You are correct, it will work w/ a very small batch of data when tested WHEN THERE ARE NO DUPLICATE MATCHES. This is key*  If it only finds one match, it will nicely copy over the adjacent data. HOWEVER, if it goes down another 2 rows and sees ANOTHER match, it doesn't know what to do with it.. That's why I needed it to know to copy THAT new finding inside same cell w/the previous finding. (like the dog/cat scenario with cat matches 3 times and the need to put the 3 cat names into one cell.)  Instead, I'm working w/ aeronautical parts but thought the dog/cat scenario might help understanding..

Comment: No need for CAPS, I understand just fine but the problem you're experiencing does not even have to do with two consecutive findings... it does not even pass the first `if` as you said.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, I added Cstr() in case of types missmatches and an "if block" for string concatenation of repeated parts:

```
 'Check if the cell is not blank:
If CStr(c2.Value) <> "" Then
     'Loop through each cell in col B in sheet 1:
    For Each c1 In rng1

         'Test if cells match: <<<<<<< THIS IS WHERE THE CODE ERRORS OUT
        If Cstr(c1.Value) = Cstr(c2.Value) Then

             'Copy value from sheet 2 to sheet 1:
            If Cstr(c1.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "" Then
                c1.Offset(0, 2).Value = CStr(c1.Offset(0, 2).Value) & ", " & CStr(c2.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            Else
                c1.Offset(0, 2).Value = CStr(c2.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            End If
             'Move on to next cell in sheet 2:
            Exit For '(exits the "For Each c1 In rng1" loop)

        End If
    Next c1
End If
```

Comment: Your '2 cents' was worth a mint! That last contribution was EXACTLY what was needed. Works beautifully! Thanks to all for the help in getting it working appropriately!